# problem while getting arrays from one class to another class

Tags: iphone

i am have 4 arrays in myclass.m

i need to get those arrays into myclassviewcontroller.m

for that i write code in myclassviewcontroller.m like this.

```
- (void)resultarrays :(NSMutableArray *)Agentids loanofficerid:(NSMutableArray *)Loanofficerid agentname:(NSMutableArray *)agentname agentemail:(NSMutableArray *)agentemail agentphone:(NSMutableArray *)Agentphone {

    agentids = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:Agentids,nil];
    loanofficerid = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:Loanofficerid,nil];
    agentnames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:agentname,nil];
    agentemails = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:agentemail,nil];
    agentphone = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:Agentphone,nil];

    NSLog(@"123 %@",agentids);
    NSLog(@"123 %@",loanofficerid);
    NSLog(@"123 %@",agentnames);
    NSLog(@"123 %@",agentphone);
}
```

in myclass.m i write this

```
myclassviewcontroller *LOVobj = [[myclassviewcontroller alloc]init];
    [LOVobj resultarrays:resultData_agent loanofficerid:array1 agentname:array2 agentemail:array3 agentphone:array4];
```

then it displays all the objects that i print in console.

After this, In the button click i print these arrays then it prints null.

even i assign setter and getter methods to it.

i did n't what's the problem can any one please help me.

Thank u in advance.

Comment: it would be helpful to see the code that prints after the button click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, change the code to this:

```
- (void)resultarrays :(NSArray *)Agentids loanofficerid:(NSArray *)Loanofficerid agentname:(NSArray *)agentname agentemail:(NSArray *)agentemail agentphone:(NSArray *)Agentphone {

    agentids = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: Agentids];
    loanofficerid = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: Loanofficerid];
    agentnames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: agentname];
    agentemails = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: agentemail];
    agentphone = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: Agentphone];

    NSLog(@"123 %@",agentids);
    NSLog(@"123 %@",loanofficerid);
    NSLog(@"123 %@",agentnames);
    NSLog(@"123 %@",agentphone);
}
```

Don't pass mutable array if you don't want it to change.

Comment: Yes i change it but there no change,it prints in console but if use this array there is shows null

Comment: - (IBAction)buttonclicked: (id)sender {
 NSLog(@"send sms clicked %@",agentids);} here i got this is null,I write this button action in myclassviewcontroller.m

Comment: Change NSLog(@"123 %@",agentids);  to  NSLog(@"123 %@ in %@",agentids, self);    in resultarrays... method    and    NSLog(@"send sms clicked %@",agentids);    to    NSLog(@"send sms clicked %@  in  %@",agentids, self);    and post the log

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're creating arrays containing references to arrays, not arrays of the objects in the parameter arrays.   And since you're storing the references of the parameter arrays, if the contents of the parameter arrays changes, so will all the references.

You probably instead want something like this for each array:

```
agentids = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: Agentids];
```

(and [agentids retain] since arrayWithArray returns an auto-released object).

Comment: Thank u for ur answer Bogatyr,But there is no change